# Accessing .Xdefaults settings from the terminal

Tags: terminal, x11

Suppose:

- I wanted to access a particular `key: value` pair in my `.Xdefaults`
- I didn't want to manually parse the file
- I must use a shell command, and only a shell command

How could I go about querying the X server for the `key`'s corresponding `value`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xrdb -query` might be what you're looking for.